# Remove Label on Material UI Select Text Field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a select field for gender which has the label positioned in the center of the select, which is the desired layout.

[image: Gender Field, nothing selected]

When the user selects this field the label flies away to the top left corner as shown. What I want to do is remove the label entirely and replace that with a blue border.

[image: Gender Field, male selected]

Here is my code:

```
          <TextField
            id='gender-select'
            select
            label="Gender"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={gender}
            onChange={data => setGender(data.target.value)}
            margin='normal'
            variant='outlined'>
            {genders.map(option => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
```

and here is my styling code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#CACACA'
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#007AFF'
      },
      '&.Mui-focused hover': {
        borderColor: '#007AFF'
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: '007AFF'
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

I have tried adding a conditional on the label prop to nullify it, eg:

`label={gender== "" ? "Gender": null}`

but this simply gives me a blank line in place of the label.

How do I change the label for a blue line when the field is in focus?

Comment: Can't you just use the placeholder property for that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason your solution didn't quite work is because TextField doesn't watch for changes to the label. It figures out the label width in [an effect](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L95) after the initial rendering.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to avoid the notch. You can prevent the label from "shrinking" up with `InputLabelProps={{shrink: false}}`.

Here is a full working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const genders = [
  {
    value: 'M',
    label: 'Male',
  },
  {
    value: 'F',
    label: 'Female',
  },
  {
    value: 'O',
    label: 'Other',
  },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 100
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  menu: {
    width: 100,
  },
}));

export default function OutlinedTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setGender(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-select-gender"
        select
        label={gender=== "" ? "Gender": ""}
        className={classes.textField}
        value={gender}
        onChange={handleChange}
        InputLabelProps={{shrink: false}}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu,
          },
        }}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
      >
        {genders.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Outlined select no shrink]

Comment: This works but produces another bug in which the label never leave and you end up writing the text over the label.

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar No, not in my example (you can play with it in the sandbox). The label is changed to empty string when the value (`gender` in the example) is not empty via `label={gender=== "" ? "Gender": ""}`.

Answer (score 13):

Try this -

```
<TextField
 sx={{ '& legend': { display: 'none' }, '& fieldset': { top: 0 },}} 
/>
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work anymore 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gryljp?file=demo.tsx

Answer (score 4):

That's the simplest way to do it:

```
      <TextField
        id='gender-select'
        select
        placeholder="Gender" // <<<<< See here
        className={classes.textField}
        value={gender}
        onChange={data => setGender(data.target.value)}
        margin='normal'
        variant='outlined'>
        {genders.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code Snippet**

```
 <TextField
  label='Type here'
  sx={{
    '& legend': { display: 'none' },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-shrink': { opacity: 0, transition: "all 0.2s ease-in" }
  }}
/>
```

**Screenshot**
[Custom Textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YOAl.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I was using styled components and this worked for me on MUI v5:

```
export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
    '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
        padding: theme.spacing(0),
        height: theme.spacing(7),
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1.5),
        paddingRight: theme.spacing(1.5)
    },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
        display: 'none'
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Dante Nuñez's example, you can use the SX property directly:

```
sx={{ "& .MuiInputLabel-root": { display: "none" } }}
```

Comment: I get an interrupted border with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

[For accessibility](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/), you should hide the content of the label while still leaving it "visible" for screen readers and other assistive technologies.
Luckily, mui has a visuallyHidden style utility that you can import from @mui/utils.

With that in mind, an easy way to hide the label while also conforming to accessibility standards is like so:

```
import { visuallyHidden } from "@mui/utils";

          <TextField
            InputLabelProps={{ sx: visuallyHidden }}
            ...
          </TextField>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `TextField` forwards props of the `FormControl`. And the latter has the [`hiddenLabel`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control/#:%7E:text=of%20its%20container.-,hiddenLabel,-bool) property. **It removes the excessive padding when the `label` prop is omitted or empty**

Demo - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#sizes